# Steps to include Jquery timepicker in MVC Web Application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I want to add a JQuery  TimePicker to my Razor View and i have spent two days on it by adding Js files and script on front end and calling that TimePicker class in my TimePicker control but all in vain.Please tell me step by step that how can i add TimePicker to my Razor View.Following is the code that i have tried..

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/timepicki.css' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/timepicki.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'>
    $('#timepicker').timepicki();
</script>

calling TimePicker in my control

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DueTime, new { @id = "timepicker" })
```

Comment: can you give the plugin link from where you downloaded?

Comment: no. buddy i forgot that..please you can provide any other

Comment: replace `<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'> $('#timepicker').timepicki();</script>` with `<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(function(){    $('#timepicker').timepicki();});
</script>`

Comment: @Guruparasad Rao here is the link from which i downloaded http://senthilraj.github.io/TimePicki/howtouse.html

Comment: I have inspected that the js and css filesd are not included in the project..how to include them ?

Comment: you have download option there in the link!! Just download it and search for required `css` and `js` files.. Keep it in your project refer them directly!!

Comment: I have download and included timepicki.css,jquery.min.js and timepicki.js but still getting error that "Failed to load resource"

Comment: Did you follow @Learner's suggestion? and if you get failed to load resource error then your file is not present in specified path!!

Comment: when i include  $('#timepicker').timepicki(); into script  time picker works but my other functions doesn't work like datepicker and autocomplete textbox..what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$(function(){

$('#timepicker').timepicki();

}

**or**

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#timepicker').timepicki();

});

Hope it works....

Answer (score 0):

A few issues with the code:
1) It is not timepicki. change it to timepicker()
2) There is no need to provide the id attribute in the html helper. The model property itself is the id.

http://jsfiddle.net/man_luck/w18qmmgt/
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#DueTime').timepicker();
});
```

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control" id="DueTime" name="DueTime" type="text">
```

use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DueTime)
```

Comment: For a basic jquery datepicker, the only files you need apart from jquery are jquery.timepicker.min.css and jquery.timepicker.min.js which you can download from http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/